# Crash : requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG On some devices

Tags: android

I have made an app that tracks call log in background using ContentObserver and service(runs in foreground).
Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
This is the permission i am checking for

```
if (CallTrackingHelper.isCallPermissionEnabled(appContext)) {
        val task = OneoffTask.Builder()
                .setService(CallLogService::class.java)
                .setExecutionWindow(0, 6)
                .setTag("call-track")
                .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_ANY)
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .build()

        val mGcmNetworkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(appContext)
        mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(task)
    }
```

i start a gcmtaskservice that uploads call-log to server

```
 override fun onRunTask(p0: TaskParams?): Int {
    val callLogs = CallTrackingHelper.getCallLog(lastSyncedIndex, this)
    //
}
```

in service i fetch contact

```
 fun getCallLog(id: Long, service: CallLogService): ArrayList<CallLogModel> {
    val callLogList = ArrayList<CallLogModel>()
    if (!isCallPermissionEnabled(service)) {
        return callLogList
    }
    var mCursor: Cursor? = null
    try {
        val args = arrayOf(id.toString())
        if (id != 0L) {
            mCursor = UCApplication
                    .getInstance()
                    .applicationContext
                    .contentResolver
                    .query(
                            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            "_id > ? ",
                            args,
                            null
                    )
        } else {
            mCursor = UCApplication
                    .getInstance()
                    .applicationContext
                    .contentResolver
                    .query(
                            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            CallLog.Calls._ID + " DESC" + " LIMIT 200 "
                    )
        }
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        //
    }
  //
    return callLogList
}

fun isCallPermissionEnabled(context: Context?): Boolean {
    if (context == null || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, PERMISSIONS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Still i am getting lot of securityException so I have to add try and catch

Comment: Please paste the security exceptions you are getting.

Comment: java.lang.Exception: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{d34d85f 31295: (pid=31295, uid=10132) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG

Comment: have you add these permission in manifest

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that if user already has an app without 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>`

in manifest and gives call permission or phone permission , after update  if these are added in update call/phone permission is still their but call log permission is not so you need to ask again.
Fresh install was working fine for me

Comment: This comment gave me the hint to my similar problem.  If you forget the "uses-permission" and then add it, it will not change unless you remove and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get run time permission in 6.0 > devices

**get runtime permission like this:**

```
    final String[] NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS };

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(DialerHomeActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //Permission is granted

    } else {

        //ask for permission

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                DialerHomeActivity.this,
                NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS, 123);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest.xml above `<appication>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>
```

you can read more at : [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

this both are their but why will i need contact permission for call_log

Comment: ah, thank you. Sorry my mistake. :D have you add this before?

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested permissions on runtime?

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}
```

}

Check this:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: i dont want to request i just want to check if permission is their thn do my job

Comment: java.lang.Exception: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{d34d85f 31295: (pid=31295, uid=10132) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Use this code for run time permission:

```java
private static final int PHONE_LOG = 1;

private void checkCallLogPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG},PHONE_LOG);

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all contact log for your mobile with this code

```java
private static final int PHONE_LOG_PERMISSION= 1;

private void checkCallLogPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG},PHONE_LOG_PERMISSION);

        return;
    }
}

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PHONE_LOG_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted
                showContacts();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```